# How to check-out particular version of webkit with svn?

Tags: svn, webkit

I want to check out this version of webkit.

Any idea how can I do it through svn?

http://trac.webkit.org/browser/releases/WebKitGTK/webkit-1.2.0

Is it possible to download only code and no .svn folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
svn co http://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit/releases/WebKitGTK/webkit-1.2.0 .
```

will check out the code into your current folder.

**EDIT:**

```
svn export http://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit/releases/WebKitGTK/webkit-1.2.0 .
```

will omit all `.svn` folders.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to download only code and no .svn folders?

Comment: use svn export to omit .svn folders.

Comment: It is currently downloading a folder which I dont require and size of it is 1 gb, Is it possible to omit some particular folder with svn export?

Comment: @Sunny: not to my knowing. Doing multiple exports of 'subfolders' omitting the *1 gb* one might be an option.

Comment: @zellus, I did the same, It works fine, Thank you very much. You saved lots of my time, I have planned to checkout through git, which takes a lot of time.

Comment: Can you please tell me, How did you guess this URL from trac url?

Comment: @Sunny: I didn't guess it from the trac URL. The subversion URL is shown here -> http://svnkit.com/download.php .

Answer (score 0):

svn export http://trac.webkit.org/browser/releases/WebKitGTK/webkit-1.2.0